# How do I modify the formula (Formula1) of a Conditional Formating of a particular cell range

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to change the Formula1 of a cell in my excel sheet and am using FormatCondition.Modify to do so. However, when this is done, this ends up duplicating mutiple formatconditions.

For example, let's say I have three formatconditions and I wanted to modify Formula1 for the first one in the index. Using FormatCondition.Modify would end up duplicating new format conditions with the new formula as well as duplicating the preexisting format conditions.This duplication would not only apply to the cell which .Modify was used, but also other cells in the row. What is even more odd is that when I would try to use FormatCondition.Delete, it would also end up deleting multiple format conditions.

**These are the rules of the cell I want to edit the formulas of:**

[image]

```vb
    Dim boe As Worksheet
    Set boe = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BoE's")
    Dim firstB As String
    firstB = "B113"

    If boe.Range(firstB).FormatConditions.Count = 3 Then
            For i = 2 To 3
                If boe.Range(firstB).FormatConditions(i).Formula1 = "=AND($I$24=""Funded"")" Then
                    boe.Range(firstB).FormatConditions(i).Modify Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:=fund
                    boe.Range(firstB).FormatConditions(i).StopIfTrue = False
                End If
                If boe.Range(firstB).FormatConditions(i).Formula1 = "=AND($I$24=""Not Funded"")" Then
                    boe.Range(firstB).FormatConditions(i).Modify Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:=nfund
                    boe.Range(firstB).FormatConditions(i).StopIfTrue = False
                End If
            Next i
        ElseIf boe.Range(firstB).FormatConditions.Count = 2 Then
            For i = 1 To 2
                If boe.Range(firstB).FormatConditions(i).Formula1 = "=AND($I$24=""Funded"")" Then
                    boe.Range(firstB).FormatConditions(i).Modify Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:=fund
                    boe.Range(firstB).FormatConditions(i).StopIfTrue = False
                End If
                If boe.Range(firstB).FormatConditions(i).Formula1 = "=AND($I$24=""Not Funded"")" Then
                    boe.Range(firstB).FormatConditions(i).Modify Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:=nfund
                    boe.Range(firstB).FormatConditions(i).StopIfTrue = False
                End If
            Next i
        End If
```

**These are the rules of the cell to the right of the cell range I have run the coode on I just modified running my code (B114):**

[image]

Is there another way to modify the Formula1 of a cell without it affect the format conditions of other cells?

Comment: Please show your code and issues w/ sample data in your post.

Comment: @taller Are the pictures added sufficent?

Comment: Please don't post images of code - you can copy/paste *all relevant code as text* so it's easier for anyone who want to help you to test out changes.